# Google OAuth - Is it possible to create an IP whitelist?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm using a Google Login component in my website that calls Google OAuth API. Is it possible to somehow define an IP whitelist together with the domains whitelist?

The expected result is that even if someone successfully identifies with a whitelisted-domain google account, it will still be rejected if their IP isn't whitelisted

Answer (score 0):

When a domain is used on the consent screen or in an OAuth client’s configuration, it must be pre-registered. If your app needs to go through verification, up need to the [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about) to check if your domains are authorized.

Domains used for a redirect uri when the app is set to production must also be verified domains.

You cant set a domain as an ip address and you wont be able to set your redirect uri as an ip address either.

Comment: Thanks. What's the right approach for allowing access to my website only through VPN?